# C# Outlook Mailitem ContextMenu and Ribbon do not work together (only separately)

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto

I need to create an Outlook add-in where the ribbon will work on the toolbar and ContextMenu (right click on mailitem).

At the beginning, I did these two things separately in separate projects.

In 1 project I add Ribbon (visual design). After launching it works very well.

In the 2 project I want to do contextmenu for mail.
In the class ThisAddIn.cs adds:

```
protected override IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return new OutlookAddInExtensibility();
        }
```

And I add class OutlookAddInExtensibility.cs:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
    public class OutlookAddInExtensibility : IRibbonExtensibility
    {
        public string GetCustomUI(string RibbonID)
        {
            return
                @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                    <customUI xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">
                        <contextMenus>    
                            <contextMenu idMso=""ContextMenuMailItem"">
                                <button 
                                    id=""MyContextMenuMailItem""
                                    label=""My new button label""
                                    onAction=""RibbonMenuClick""
                                />
                            </contextMenu>  
                        </contextMenus>
                    </customUI>
                ";
        }

        public void RibbonMenuClick(IRibbonControl control)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Show text");
        }
```

After launching it works very well.

Unfortunately, when I add these two things in one project - only ContectMenu works. The ribbon at the top does not show up.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Eugene Astafiev's help I found a solution. Export RibbonVisualDesigner to XML. And adding code from ContextMenu to XML. Two in one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="testTab" label="Test Label">
        <group id="testGroup" label="test">
          <button id="testButton" onAction="testAction" label="Test" size="large"
              getImage ="GetCustomImage" screentip="Test Ribbon Functionality."/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
  <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
      <button idMso="FontDialog" visible="false" />
      <toggleButton id="MyToggle" label="My Toggle Button" />
      <button id="MyButton" label="My Button" insertBeforeMso="HyperlinkInsert" onAction="GetButtonID" />
      <menuSeparator id="MySeparator" />
      <menu id="MySubMenu" label="My Submenu" >
        <button id="MyButton2" label="Button on submenu" />
      </menu>
      <gallery id="galleryOne" label="My Gallery">
        <item id="item1" imageMso="HappyFace" />
        <item id="item2" imageMso="HappyFace" />
        <item id="item3" imageMso="HappyFace" />
        <item id="item4" imageMso="HappyFace" />
      </gallery>
      <dynamicMenu id="MyDynamicMenu" label= "My Dynamic Menu" getContent="GetMyContent" />
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

Comment: Marking your own posts as answers doesn't make any sense. Only those, who really helped, can benefit from that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose a single way for customizing the UI - export the ribbon UI designed in Visual Studio to a ribbon XML file and then combine them together. Don't forget to return an appropriate markup depending on the `RibbonID` parameter passed to the `GetCustomUI` method.

There are two ways for creating a custom UI in Office applications (in VSTO):

1. [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019)
2. [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019)

Due to the fact that VSTO ribbon designer doesn't provide and support all ribbon features you need to export the existing UI into XML and continue dealing with it.

See [How to: Export a ribbon from the Ribbon Designer to Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-export-a-ribbon-from-the-ribbon-designer-to-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019) for more information.